# What are the legal restrictions on extracting audio from a virtual instrument plugin?

Tags: united-states, dmca

This question was inspired by https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/113826/is-there-a-way-to-decode-triton-m1-vst-pcm-samples

Suppose a user purchases a license for virtual instrument *plugin* to make music with.  This license includes the standard allowances to use sounds produced by *plugin* in a broader work, commercial or otherwise.  *Plugin* includes several audio clips which it plays back with some fancy modifications to produce interesting sounds.  These audio clips are not immediately accessible; they are contained in some other file, or perhaps encoded with a non-obvious codec.

The user wishes to take these sounds and modify them with a different virtual instrument to make other sounds. He locates the sounds, convert them to a standard format (if necessary), and uses them as he pleases, thinking that the use of these sounds is bound by the same license agreement as the plugin itself.

Let's also suppose that the license does not address the possibility that a user extracts audio data from the plugin files to use.  Of course this would be illegal if the license agreement forbids it.

What law, if any, might the user be violating?

Answers specific to other countries are also welcome.

Comment: You can bet that the license forbids it.

Comment: Can I? I would look at the license agreement myself if I could find it.  But every plugin I own either lets you access this kind of data directly or lets you play the raw sounds without any modification, without any file digging.